# Xcode 7.1 - symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode

I'm  trying to run my app on an iPhone5S (connected) not sim.
The project references a static libary. I did lipo on it and it supports
i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64.

When I run I get 
ld: symbols(s) not found for arch arm64

Under Build Settings, Arch... 
   I have $(ARCHS_STANDARD)    in bold is armv7 and arm64

Any ideas.... this is driving me crazy
thanks in advance

Comment: What symbols are not found? Symbols from the .lib? Or maybe you're missing a reference to a framework.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the lib...  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AID_OTP" in FirstViewController.... that's where I call the lib

Comment: Is there anything I need to do the .a file?  I'm very new at this. thx

Comment: You've added the library in the link step in the project's settings? e.g. Add -lname-of-my-lib to "Other Linker Flags".

Comment: I get library not found for -llibaotp

Comment: library is libaotp.a

Comment: Simple Solution
Go to Target ->Linking -> other linker Flag and add $(inherited) in other linker flag in both Debug and Release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In your project settings, add -llibaotp to "Other Linker Flags".
2. Add the path to the library to "Library Search Paths".

Alternatively, add the library to the Link Binary with Libraries build phase (for screenshots see https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp).

Comment: This process is shared by just about all build systems. Xcode is merely passing these flags down to Clang or GCC or whatever the underlying toolchain is. You'd have the same with Visual Studio, make, ...

Comment: I am sure there is a reason, but this started happening overnight, not to mention XCode now runs so slow, it is impossible to work. @GrahamPerks